# docker-compose use extra_hosts with container id

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized app that needs to talk to an external (not dockerized) oracle database.

The app works on my local machine only if I append the result of the `hostname` command to the `localhost` entry in my `/etc/hosts` file. Otherwise I get an error from the OracleDB driver:

> Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection
>   with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently
>   know of service requested in connect descriptor

I could log in my container and edit `/etc/hosts` manually, I would like to avoid this manual step after rebuilding. How do I keep this file up to date?

Furthermore it seems the `hostname` set by docker is the container id.

Is there a way to reference a container id from inside the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe easily way is set specific hostname for container?

Set `hostname: foo` in your docker-compose file and then use hostname *foo* instead hosname based on docker id.

Answer (score 0):

turns out hostname: is not used for networking in other containers.